# Acessar dados de dois bancos de dados de duas tabelas diferentes em uma query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Galera, estou tendo um problema.
Atualmente tenho dois bancos de dados e duas tabelas (1 tabela em cada banco) que precisam ser conectadas em uma `query` só. Seria um `JOIN` em outras palavras, porém não estou conseguindo entender como faço isso em outro banco de dados.

A conexão entre os bancos tem o mesmo usuário e senha, porém tem chamadas diferentes.

Banco Financeiro = `$financeiro->query();`

Banco Clientes/Site = `$site->query();`

Tentei aplicar um JOIN e alguns outros resultados que encontrei no Google porém não obtive sucesso quando preciso acessar outro banco.

Atualmente temos o campo `cliente` na tabela do `financeiro` e o campo `chns` na tabela de `clientes`, onde o `chns` é o código único de cliente que é usado em todo o resto do sistema para identificação.

Queria o SQL nesse estilo (se possível) que já uso em conexões dentro do mesmo banco:

`$financeiro->query("SELECT * FROM financeiro AS FA JOIN clientes AS CL ON FA.cliente = CL.chns ORDER BY CL.nome ASC")`;

As conexões são feitas todas em `PDO`.

Comment: Qual foi a _query_ que você tentou fazer mas não funcionou? Edite a sua pergunta e a adicione.

Comment: Os bancos de dados estão no mesmo servidor ou estão em servidores diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples assim:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1 tbl_1
JOIN database2.table2 tbl_2 on tbl_1.ID = tbl_2.ID
```